# ROR: Higher development speed than others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

It's been shown that Ruby On Rails isn't especially fast in a performance perspective. Even PHP may be faster, but obviously there's other things that adds up to the cons of Ruby On Rails. Development speed is among those and commonly mentioned by people as one of ROR's biggest strengths.

However I have not seen any objective opinions on this. Does Ruby On Rails really help to keep development speeds lower than other web application programming languages?

Comment: You could look at this question on quora http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-tradeoffs-e-g-development-speed-performance-scalability-between-using-various-php-frameworks-ruby-rails-or-python-django-Is-there-any-reason-to-choose-one-overwhelmingly-over-another?q=development+speed+ruby+on+rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very controversial subject (in fact, I expect this to get closed!).

I would argue that RoR *can* deliver faster development, but only if you're doing it right. The fact that it's so opinionated about some of the common tasks that come up during most development encourages you to do it right... it makes testing easier, for example, and virtually forces you to keep view logic separate from models.

And that said, performance wise, Rails 3 isn't exactly slow! In fact, I've found it (in my own, completely unscientific experiments) to perform better than Zend Framework for PHP.